# Remove string element from one column from another

Tags: awk, sed

I have an input file. The first string of the third column will be always the fourth column. I want to remove the third column string from the first column.

The input format is

```
7    6502549    TA        T
7    6502822    GAAGAA    G
17   8347553    TAA       T
17   8354321    CG        C
17   8363312    CCTT      C
17   8366613    AAT       A
17   8366623    CCTTT     C
```

The desired output is

```
    7    6502549    A        T
    7    6502822    AAGAA    G
    17   8347553    AA       T
    17   8354321    G        C
    17   8363312    CTT      C
    17   8366613    AT       A
    17   8366623    CTTT     C
```

Comment: what if they are not matching?

Comment: You could get that output by just removing the first character from the 3rd column regardless of any value of the 4th column - why isn't that a good enough statement of your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**awk**

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{sub($4,"",$3)}1' f1
7   6502549 A   T
7   6502822 AAGAA   G
17  8347553 AA  T
17  8354321 G   C
17  8363312 CTT C
17  8366613 AT  A
17  8366623 CTTT    C
```

`sub($4,"",$3)` : `sub` will substitute the fourth field character's first occurence in third field with an empty character

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

if doesn't match, no replacement takes place...

```
$ awk '{sub("^"$4,"",$3)}1' file | column -t

7   6502549  A      T
7   6502822  AAGAA  G
17  8347553  AA     T
17  8354321  G      C
17  8363312  CTT    C
17  8366613  AT     A
17  8366623  CTTT   C
```

Comment: Is it just me or `awk` under Cygwin has known issues that would prevent your one-liner to work?

Comment: perhaps, not sure.  You may need to save the script in a file and call with `awk -f script.awk file`.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki no, that command will work under cygwin or in any other UNIX environment (that has column of course).

Answer (score 0):

If your data is valid and first character of the 3rd column is always the 4th column you can just remove the first character of the 3rd column with `substr`:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,substr($3,2),$4}' in.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the solution does not have to be either sed or awk, use cut:

```
cut --complement -c 17
```

Output for sample input:

```
7    6502549    A        T
7    6502822    AAGAA    G
17   8347553    AA       T
17   8354321    G        C
17   8363312    CTT      C
17   8366613    AT       A
17   8366623    CTTT     C
```

Explanation:
Cut the 17th character `-c 17`.
But invert the selection to print `--complement`.

*(Note: This answer is intentionally slightly provocative. It would not hurt to trigger some elaboration by OP on special cases, e.g. when there is no identity or for empty lines or lines which do not match the very static pattern which is applicable to all shown sample input lines.)*